# CORS ERROR, ACTIVE DIRECTORY AUTHENTICATION

Tags: node.js, nginx, azure-active-directory, cors, passport.js

I'm having a tough time with some cors errors. Basically im trying to authenticate users with active directory using the OIDC passport strategy. My Front end is a vuejs app served through NGINX at http://localhost:80. The home page has a button to login through active directory. This makes a request to the nodejs backend at http://localhost:3001. It hits this route:

```
router.get('/ad',
  function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', 
      { 
        response: res,                      // required
        // resourceURL: config.resourceURL,    // optional. Provide a value if you want to specify the resource.
        // customState: 'my_state',            // optional. Provide a value if you want to provide custom state value.
        // failureRedirect: '/' 
      }
    )(req, res, next);
  },
  function(req, res) {
    log.info('Login was called in the Sample');
});
```

This makes a request to the active directory server of course, but the response doesn't have an access allow origin header. So im getting some cors preflight errors. I have access to the active directory application but there doesn't seem to be a way to resolve this

I set my cors options in the express server as so:

```
const corsOptions ={
  origin:'http://localhost', 
  credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
  optionSuccessStatus:200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Here is the error i get from chrome:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/8d0d81ba-ed03-4c6f-9248-a3b3967ca35c/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3001%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fauth%2Fad%2Fcallback&response_type=code%20id_token&response_mode=form_post&client_id=446e6d62-6ba4-4c84-a9d6-8f255e576fff&state=8RyjKRutfEb2RO6ymqkRoo4br-CWUPCV&nonce=BGg4eP-lrNMPuJyn3R7bsnXJhLFhdWc9&scope=profile%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read%20openid&x-client-SKU=passport-azure-ad&x-client-Ver=4.3.2' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/auth/ad') from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In edge surprisingly i get a different error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/auth/userinfo' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Heres the axios request:

```
       ad_login: function() {
          console.log(this.login.password)
          axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/auth/ad', { withCredentials: true } ).then(data => {
              console.log(data);
              console.log(data.status)
              console.log(data.request.responseURL)
              window.location.replace(data.request.responseURL)

              // this.$get_user_info()
          })
       },
```

I need to use credentials so setting the request credentials to false isn't an option. And setting the wildcard as the origin fails as well. The only thing I've read up on that felt promising was using a cors proxy. Is there a way to add the headers to the active directory response? Or do I need a proxy? how may I go about implementing one?

Comment: If you have a Single Page Application as your front-end, I'd recommend using MSAL.js (Authorization Code with PKCE flow), and configuring your back-end to only validate the JSON Web Tokens sent by your front-end. The way you have it configured now requires your front-end to actually redirect the user to that URL, you can't access it with Axios etc.

Comment: I don't have a single page application front. Is there no way to pass the cors pre flight with credentials then just redirect to the link the OIDC returned?

Answer (score -1):

You can actually set access-control-allow-origin headers in the nginx.conf file.    You can see some examples here:
https://gist.github.com/Stanback/7145487

This might work out to be a better solution for you.

Answer (score -2):

Ended up Serving the vue app from the express server to get around this instead of nginx. not a great answer but a work around for anyone with a similar issue